# Cannot save processed fingerprint image with VeriFinger

Tags: c++, image-processing, fingerprint

I'm trying to use an SDK called [VeriFinger](http://neurotechnology.com/verifinger.html), from [Neurotechnology](http://neurotechnology.com/), to process a BMP file containing a fingerprint capture (for enhancement), and save it to a new BMP file.

VeriFinger comes with a few tutorials and samples, the main one being called *FingersSampleWX*.

It looks like this:

[image: FingersSampleWX screenshot]

Following this application's source code as a guide, I was able to assemble this piece of code which *should* do what I want, or so I believe:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <NLicensing.hpp>
#include <NMedia.hpp>
#include <NBiometrics.hpp>

using namespace Neurotec::Biometrics;
using namespace Neurotec::Images;
using namespace Neurotec::Licensing;

int main()
{
    if (NLicense::ObtainComponents("/local", "5000", "Biometrics.FingerExtraction"))
        std::wcout << L"License OK\n";
    else
        std::wcout << L"License fail\n";

    NFinger finger;
    finger.SetFileName("F:\\input\\000001\\MDT1.BMP");
    finger.SetPosition(nfpUnknown);
    finger.SetImpressionType(nfitNonliveScanPlain);

    // testing
    auto test1 = finger.GetFileName();
    auto test2 = finger.GetImage();
    auto test3 = finger.GetProcessedImage();

    NImage image(NULL);
    if (finger.GetHandle())
    {
        image = finger.GetProcessedImage();

        if (image.GetHandle())
            image.Save("F:\\output\\000001\\MDT1_out.bmp");
    }   
    NLicense::ReleaseComponents("Biometrics.FingerExtraction");
}
```

However, the image won't save. For some reason, the line `if (image.GetHandle())` returns `false`. That's why I added the `testing` section.

Checking the value of `test2` and `test3` using the debugger tells me:

> handle=0x00000000  isDisposed=false

`GetProcessedImage()` returns `NULL`, which is very weird, because `test1` returns the file name of the `finger` object correctly. I'm sure missing something... Been struggling with this for a few hours now.

VeriFinger is [available as a 30-day trial](http://www.neurotechnology.com/download.html#megamatcher_verifinger_verilook_verieye_sdk_trial) (700MB). The SDK documentation is located in the `Documentation` folder in both CHM and PDF formats.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have access to VeriFinger SDK documentation that you'd be willing to share?

Comment: @oldrinb Just found out they have the SDK documentation on their website: http://www.neurotechnology.com/download.html - Btw it's also possible to download the "Biometric SDKs trials" which contains the sample's source.

Comment: I didn't look at the SDK, but do you need to do something to load the finger after setting the filename and other parameters?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm The sample app aparently doesn't need to, and I really can't tell just from looking at the docs or with the help of Intellisense.

Comment: what does ```auto test2 = finger.GetImage()``` return? At this stage, I'm guessing your image isn't being processed correctly.

Comment: @Marc I have an issue, in which folder did you put your code for it to work fine? I want to developt a simple app, but I don't know where in the sdk folder should I put my code?

Comment: @juliansalas I didn't put my code in the SDK folder at all, I have it somewhere else and I've put `D:\Dev\Neurotec_Biometric_5_0_SDK\Include` to my compiler's "Includes Path". If that's not what you're asking, create a new question and link to it here so I can have a look.

Comment: help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63542163/verifinger-11-2-invalid-sample-resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the image saving to work, one must first:

1. define an object of type `Client::NBiometricClient`
2. call its member function `SetFingersReturnProcessedImage()` using the `true` as argument
3. define an object of type `NSubject`
4. call its member function `SetId()` which takes an argument of type `NStringWrapper` - this type has a default constructor for C-style strings (null-terminated char arrays), same as `finger.SetFileName()` from the example in the question
5. call another of its member function, `GetFingers()`, and call `Add()` on the returned object, using as argument for `Add()` the object of type `NFinger` which was defined previously (it's called `finger` in the question body)
6. define an object of type `NBiometricTask` and initialize it with a call to another member function from the object defined at step 1, which is `CreateTask()` and takes two arguments: `nboEnroll` (an enum) and `NULL`
7. call its member function `GetSubjects()` and call `Add()` on the returned object, using as argument for `Add()` the object defined at step 3
8. call another member function from the object defined at step 1, this one's `PerformTask()`, using as argument the object defined at step 6.

**It looks simpler in practice:**

```
// (previous code from question)
NFinger finger;
finger.SetFileName("F:\\input\\000001\\MDT1.BMP");
finger.SetPosition(nfpUnknown);
finger.SetImpressionType(nfitNonliveScanPlain);

// Needed initializations:
Client::NBiometricClient m_biometricClient;
m_biometricClient.SetFingersReturnProcessedImage(true);
NBiometricTask task = m_biometricClient.CreateTask(nboEnroll, NULL);

NSubject subject;
subject.SetId("F:\\input\\000001\\MDT1.BMP");   // I'm just using the filename as argument as its purpose is rather temporary
subject.GetFingers().Add(finger);

task.GetSubjects().Add(subject);
m_biometricClient.PerformTask(task);
// ok, everything should work now

// (...)
```

---

Thanks to [user3791372](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3791372/user3791372) for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

From perusing the sample code and from doing some reading, it looks like your problem is one of two possible problems.

Either the image is not correct. I could not find much more information than the input image not being liked so try a few different input images of different sizes. This is why I ask what does `GetImage()` output into the test2 var? If that doesn't work properly, then it suggests that your input image isn't liked.

In all the sample code I read, the NFinger instance appears to be added to a subject before any operations is done on the NFinger instance. I'm not sure if this modifies the NFinger instance in some way as the documentation seems to be fairly light. Looking at NSubject.hpp, it suggests that the finger is added to a FingersCollection, but doesn't appear to do much more.

Before the "testing" section, add the finger code to a subject:

```
NSubject subject;
subject.SetId("Some Unique String");
subject.GetFingers().Add(finger);
```

Finally, failing this, look into the use of the `m_biometricClient` variable in the sample code, especially the initialization of it, `m_biometricClient.SetFingersReturnProcessedImage(true)` looks interesting doesn't it! There's quite a bit of initialisation code which you will see in the FingersSampleForm.cpp. When the finger is added, the client appears to be responsible for enrolling it via a task (see the `void FingersSampleForm::OnEnroll)` method with the operation of `nboEnroll`.

Comment: Hey, with your insights I was able to get it working. Soon I'll (most likely) award you the bounty. Thanks!

Comment: That's great news! What was the issue?

Comment: Hey, took me more than two years, but I finally added my answer. Have a look if you'd like. Regards